# Can the non-theorems of arithmetic be effectively listed?

Tags: logic

Consider the set of all first-order sentences over the signature $(0,S)$. Each of these is either true with respect to standard model of arithmetic $(\mathbb{N},0,S)$, or it false. The set of all such true sentences cannot be listed by an effective procedure — this is a consequence of the Gödel incompleteness theorems. Can the same be said of the set of all such false sentences?

Comment: since the incompleteness is proved, it is a fact. There is no way around it.

Comment: What do you mean by "system"?

Comment: @PeterSmith, a set of first order axioms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The false statements are not recursively enumerable either. If they were, you could enumerate the *true* statements by:

1. Enumerate all false statements.
2. Whenever one of the false statements found has the form $\neg \phi$, output $\phi$.